# Bouncing image animation loop

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to loop an animation of each object bouncing one after another and then bouncing in the opposite direction - piano roll style.

I'm at a loss as to why this code doesn't function.

```
<script type=text/javascript>
$.fn.exBounce = function(){
var self = this;
(function runEffect(){
    self.delay(500).effect("bounce", { direction:'down', times:1 }, 200);
})();
};


function animatebounce() {

   $(".bounce").each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(500 * i).exBounce(function(){
         $($(".bounce").get().reverse()).each(function(i) {
            $(this).delay(200 * i).exBounce();
         });
      });
   });
};



$(document).ready(function(){
animatebounce();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@asawilliams is right. 
You need to define callback as a paramater in your plugin and then call it 
http://jsfiddle.net/gaboesquivel/ZRZEA/7/

Comment: Thanks so much! :D Any idea why the order is haphazard on the descend?

Comment: I've changed the code a little, I hope it answers your question http://jsfiddle.net/gaboesquivel/ZRZEA/22/  ... however I'm pretty sure there's a simpler way to accomplish the same effect

Comment: Who's awesome? YOU ARE! Thanks so much, I'm certainly a beginner so this is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin doesn't take a parameter; the function you are passing in will not get called.

Comment: How do I make it take a parameter?